# Move operator destroying original pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to have a pointer to a memory location.
Then, if I modify the original the assigned variable
who points to the same location must be also affected by the change.

But, the thing is, there are two function calls, that happen on line:

```
a = Data("New data");
```

1. `Data(const char* cdata)` constructor is called.
2. `Data operator=(Data&& data)` move operator is called.

EDIT: I am aware of the folloing:

- **std::shared_ptr<>**
- **std::make_shared<>**

but, I am trying to accomplish this without these new features. I am fully aware.

**My C++ code:**

```
class Data 
{
private:
    char* local_data;
    int _size = 0;
    int length(const char* c)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(c[++i] != '\0');
        return i;
    }
public:
    Data() {
        local_data = new char[_size];
    }
    
    Data(const char* cdata){
        _size = length(cdata);
        local_data = new char[_size];
        memcpy(local_data, cdata, _size);
    }
    
    int size() { return _size; }
    char* data() { return local_data; }
    const char* data() const { return local_data; }
    
    Data& operator=(const Data& data){}
    Data& operator=(Data&& data){
        
        if(this == &data)
            return *this;
        
        _size = std::move(data.size());
        local_data = std::move(data.data());
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(){
    
    Data a("Some data");
    auto dptr = a.data(); // Gives a pointer to the original location
    a = Data("New data"); // Must modify both a and dptr
    assert(dptr == a.data()); // Should pass successfully, else fail
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_size` is always `0`, so you are always allocating 0 bytes and copying 0 bytes.

Comment: The `_size` part here is irrelevant. Atm. What's relevant, is the `move operator`.

Comment: *"Must modify both a and dptr"* - that's not going to happen with move-semantics. `dptr` is a plain `const char*`.Your move-assignment operator is literally replacing the pointer held as `local_data` with a different value. I'm not even going to attempt to understand what on earth you want to do this for, but one way could (highly questionably) do it is by having `data()` return a `const char *&` (i.e. a reference to the member rather than a copy of its value. Be warned; this is a terrible idea and a recipe fro a dangling reference.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks. I don't want dangling pointers or memory leaks for that matter.

Comment: *"The _size part here is irrelevant."*, so don't include it for M(inimal)CVE.

Comment: Avoid to edit question to invalidate existing answers.

Comment: A dangling reference is arguably *worse* (and at best, no better). Jarod's solution of using a shared_ptr is the correct approach. Ir properly reference counts and properly maintains dual (or more) ownership. Were it me, I'd take it and don't look back.

Comment: Still, if I would have done it that way, I wouldn't be here asking. As I have written, I am fully aware of the new features. But, again, without those. I am trying to accomplish without those.

Comment: What else do you want? As I said, you're not going to get there from here. Not without a dreadfully brittle architecture, as I tried (apparently in vain), to drive home in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your `class Data`. First, it never calls `delete[] local_data`, so it will leak memory. Add a destructor:

```
~Data() {
    delete[] local_data;
}
```

Then ensure your move assignment operator works correctly. Don't use `std::move(data.data())`, this does not in fact set the pointer in the object that is moved from to `nullptr`. Also, ensure you clean up `this->local_data` properly. The easiest way to do this is:

```
Data& operator=(Data&& data){
    std::swap(local_data, data.local_data);
    std::swap(_size, data._size);
    return *this;
}
```

It swaps the pointers around, so there is no memory leak. After the move, the destruction of `data` will ensure the old `this->local_data` is deleted.

Your copy assignment operator is empty, you should fix that, and if you have a move assignment operator you probably also want to implement a move constructor. Finally:

```
assert(dptr == a.data()); // Should pass successfully, else fail
```

This is wrong; `dptr` should not be the same as `a.data()`, since `dptr` is a *copy* of the pointer to the data taken from before the move assignment. The value of `dptr` will not change unless you explicitly modify `dptr`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`:

```
class Data 
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> local_data = std::make_shared<std::string>();
public:
    Data() = default;
    
    Data(const char* cdata) : local_data(std::make_shared<std::string>(cdata)) {}
    
    int size() const { return local_data->size(); }
    char* data() { return local_data->data(); }
    const char* data() const { return local_data->c_str(); }
    
    Data operator=(const Data& rhs) {
        if (this == &data)
            return *this;
        
        *local_data = *rhs.local_data;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(){
    
    Data a("Some data");
    auto dptr = a.data(); // Gives a pointer to the original location
    a = Data("New data"); // Must modify both a and dptr
    assert(dptr == a.data()); // Should pass successfully
}
```

Comment: Hi Jarod42, thx. I don't want to use that here, `std::shared_ptr`. But, I am fully aware. Let me look more closely at what you are doing.

Comment: Without, `std::make_shared`. How can this be accomplied the regular way?

Comment: Regular way is to use tools provided by std :) I even think that `std::unique_ptr` is enough (and is simpler to rewrite, if you cannot use std).

Comment: Jarod, but without that. ?

Comment: If you cannot use std stuff, write your own (simplified) version, then you might use them, instead of restarting from scratch for each class. If you don't know how to write equivalent to `std::string`/`std::unique_ptr`/`std::vector`, do a search, then ask specific question about that.

Comment: OMG! Dude, what have I written in my code? Data is a class. It holds text information. I simply, want to to this with the traditional way, using a "pointer". If you look closely at my move operator semantics, you can see that I am using: `std::move`

Comment: Traditional way to handle text is `std::string`.... Moving pointer is just .. copy.